# How to replay in a deterministic way in CQRS / event-sourcing?

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

In CQRS / ES based systems, you store events in an event-store. These events refer to an aggregate, and they have an order with respect to the aggregate they belong to. Furthermore, aggregates are consistency / transactional boundaries, which means that any transactional guarantees are only given on a per-aggregate level.

Now, supposed I have a read model which consumes events from *multiple* aggregates (which is perfectly fine, AFAIK). To be able to replay the read model in a deterministic way, the events need some kind of global ordering, across aggregates – otherwise you wouldn't know whether to replay events for aggregate A before or after the ones for B, or how to intermix them.

The simplest solution to achieve this is by using a timestamp on the events, but typically timestamps are not fine-granular enough (or, to put it another way, not all databases are created equal). Another option is to use a global sequence, but this is bad performance-wise and hinders scaling.

How do you solve this issue? Or is my basic assumption, that replays of read models should be deterministic, wrong?

Comment: Can you give an example of when it would matter that aggregate A get replayed before aggregate B?

Comment: Supposed you have two aggregates, `group` and `user`, and users can be part of groups. For sure, you don't want groups and users to be part of the same aggregate, as this would dramatically reduce parallel usage of the software. However, before a user is able to join a group, the group must exist. While this can easily be resolved on the write side, how to decide in which order to replay a group's and user's events in the read side, to avoid that in the `groups of each user` view you try to add a group to a user's record where the user is not there yet?

Comment: @GoloRoden (Removed my previous comment as I think I missunderstood) - In our own implementation we used stream names in our event store and were able to replay events for a specific set of streams allowing us to control the order. i.e: $ce-groups then $ce-users etc...

Comment: @Nope Okay, but do you figure this order out automatically, or is it something a developer has to define?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see these options:

- Global sequence

  - if your database allows it, you can use timestamp+aggregateId+aggregateVersion as an index. This usually doesnt work well in the distributed database case.
  - in the distributed database you can use [vector clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_clock) to get a global sequence without having a lock.
- Event sequence inside each read model. You can literally store all events in the read model and sort them as you want before applying a projection function.
- Allow non-determinism and deal with it. For instance, in your example, if there is no group when add_user event arrives - just create an empty group record to the read model and add a user. And when create_group event arrives - update that group record.
  After all, you have checked in UI and/or command handler that there
  is a group with this aggregateId, right?

Comment: `if there is no group when add_user event arrives - just create a group and add a user` - If the AddUser command handler checks the group exist would the command not be rejected if the group does not exist? Are you suggesting if the group doesn't exist the AddUser command handler should send a AddGroup command? Would that not introduce tight coupling and potentially introduce errors if the AddUser command was triggered for an invalid group?

Comment: @Nope - we are talking about read side, so I assume that business rules were checked - meaining that events are correct in the stream, they just not in the right order. So I assume that user was added to an existing group, otherwise UI or command handlers would not allow this event to exist.

Comment: Yes, the event would not exist otherwise. I am still confused what was suppose to create the group in your suggestions as the UserAdded event would only write the user data to the read data store and would not have to worry about the group to exist at that point and on the query/read side, the query would fail to find the user for a group that doesn't exist until the group events are replayed. Sorry, I am obviously just misunderstanding things. Still getting my head around those things myself :)

Comment: In our experience we can see some events to be late in order of milliseconds. So in this example group record in the read model would be fully updated withing a second - which is usually acceptable. 
In our system (reSolve) we are using vector clock as mentioned here, so we don't have this problem. But vector clock is not free- we need to re-query events if order is wrong, so ignoring order problem is a cheapest solution if it possible.

Answer (score 1):

> How do you solve this issue?

It's known issue, and of course nor simple timestamps, nor global sequence, nor event naïve methods will not help.
Use [vector clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_clock) with weak timestamp to enumerate your events and vector cursor to read them. That guarantees some stable deterministic order to intermix events between aggregates. This will work even if each thread has clock synchronization gap, which is regular use case for database clusters, because perfect timestamp synchronization is impossible.
Also this automatically gives possibility to seamless mix reading events from event store and event bus later, and excludes any database locks inter different aggregates events.

Algorithm draft:
1) Determine real quantity of simultaneous transactions in your database, e.g. maximum number of workers in cluster.
Since every event had been written in only one transaction in one thread, you can determine it's unique id as tuple `(thread number, thread counter)`, where thread counter is amount of transactions processed on current thread.
Calculate event weak timestamp as `MAX(thread timestamp, aggregate timestamp)`, where aggregate timestamp is timestamp of last event for current aggregate.

2) Prepare vector cursor for reading events via thread number boundary. Read events from each thread sequentially until timestamp gap exceed allowed value. Allowed weak timestamp gap is trade between event reading performance and preserving native events order.
Minimal value is cluster threads synchronization time delta, so events are arrived in native aggregate intermix order. Maximum value is infinity, so events will be spitted by aggregate. When using RDBMS like postgres, that value can be automatically determined via smart SQL query.

You can see referent implementation for PostgreSQL database for [saving events](https://github.com/reimagined/resolve/blob/dev/packages/adapters/storage-adapters/resolve-storage-postgresql/src/save-event.js) and [loading events](https://github.com/reimagined/resolve/blob/dev/packages/adapters/storage-adapters/resolve-storage-postgresql/src/load-events-by-cursor.js). Saving events performance is about 10000 events per second for 4GB RAM RDS Postgres cluster.

Comment: the link is broken, mind updating ? thanks

Comment: @kuldeep See there https://github.com/reimagined/resolve/blob/dev/packages/runtime/adapters/eventstore-adapters/eventstore-postgresql/src/load-events-by-cursor.ts and there https://github.com/reimagined/resolve/blob/dev/packages/runtime/adapters/eventstore-adapters/eventstore-postgresql/src/save-event.ts